# Looping through an array that has binary numbers and writing true if the number is 1 or false if the number is 0

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make a webpage that makes an encrypted letter by first parsing a single character in ascii then parsing the ascii into binary then putting the binary into an array. After putting it into an array I have to loop through the array and write true for "1" or false for "0". Then I have to output to the page. an example of what the output would look like if you put in the letter "a" would be "false,true,true,false,false,false,false,true"

Update: I have added the "loop" in order to make sense of my problem

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    var strQuestion = "Enter ONE character, matey!";
    var strStandard = "J";
    var chrCharacter = "";
    var chrLength = 0;
    var array = [];
    var arrayLength = 0;
    while (chrLength != 1)
    {
    chrCharacter = prompt(strQuestion, strStandard);
    chrLength = chrCharacter.length;
    }
    intAscii = parseAscii(chrCharacter);

    strBin = parseBin(intAscii);

    array = strBin.split("");

        for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++ )
        {
         if (array[i] = 0)
          {
          array[i] = false;
          }
         else if (array[i] = 1)
          {
          array[i] = true;

        }

}



    output.innerHTML = array;




    }); //end document.ready



    /*****          
    Purpose: Converts a character into ascii        
    Parameters: single character / letter       
    Return: integer representing an ascii value
    *****/
    function parseAscii(chrCharacter)
    {
        intAscii = chrCharacter.charCodeAt(0);
        return intAscii;
    }

    /*****          
    Purpose: Takes the ascii code and turns it into binary          
    Parameters: single integer representing an ascii value  
    Return: binary, base 2 representation of the number passed to this function
    *****/
    function parseBin(intAscii)
    {
        strBin = parseInt(intAscii, 10).toString(2);
        if(strBin.length < 8)
        {
            var intPlaceHolders = 8 - strBin.length;
            for(var i = 0; i < intPlaceHolders; i++)
            {
                strBin = "0" + strBin;
            }

        }

        return strBin;
    }
```

Comment: Remember that in JavaScript in the browser you don't need things like `prompt`, you can use regular forms and a submit button.

Comment: `//Where the loop would be` - Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can convert your array of ones and zeros (binary) to values of ture and false using the `map` function and using `innerHTML` to add the output to the DOM:

See example below:

```js
// Populate myBinaryArray using your ascii method to get the follow:
let myBinaryArray = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1];
document.body.innerHTML += myBinaryArray.map(bit => !(!bit));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the array with binaries to an array with boolean values wich you can joint together to a string that can be shown on the webpage.

```
array = [1,1,0,0,1]

// This will map over the items and perform an type conversion 
var booleanArray = array.map(Boolean)

// Join all the items together as a string
Var booleanString = booleanArray.join(", ")

output.innerHTML = booleanString
```

`

I didn't test it, but it should work if I didn't make any typo's.

---

Btw, I dont think that this is what they ment with *looping*. But it's definitely a way to get the job done.